# a C# class derived from a template

Tags: class, inheritance, c#-4.0

I am new to c#, recently I read the source of code of Oxygen not include(using dnspy), which have some confusing code. I tried google but nothing helpful can be found.

Threr is a class called ElementEntry derived from a template class YamlIO。
what confuse me is that this template take the parameter T same as the class ElementEntry.

I think this may cause some problem. Am I right?

```cs
public class YamlIO<T>
{
...
}
public class ElementEntry : YamlIO<ElementEntry>
{
...
}
```

Comment: Templates are a C++ concept. C# generics are different. What you see isn't forbidden - essentially, `YamlIO` adds some extra functionality to `ElementEntry` through inheritance. The *problem* is that this is done through inheritance, which implies a non-existent `is-a` relation and makes adding different services (eg serlialization) a lot harder - `ElementEntry` is tight to the YamlIO implementation now, whether it likes it or not. Should YamlIO change, ElementEntry also changes

Comment: You can see this as an attempt to add the `YamlIO` trait το ElementEntry. The problem is that C# doesn't have multiple inheritance and so `ElementEntry` *becomes* a YamlIO. At the very least, this makes implementing a proper domain a lot harder. Adding another trait, would require something like `ElementEntry: YamlIO<SomOtheStuff<ElementEntry>>` - assuming that YamlIO also inherited from T. Things start getting *very* complicated